# Base Class for Tab Index in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, tabindex

I'm trying to create a nice generic way of setting the tab index on many elements in a page of an ASP.NET app (using VB.NET). As a result I was wondering if there was a base class that controls implementing the TabIndex property inherited from so I could generate the following code:

```
Public Sub GenerateTabIndex(order as List(Of TabIndexBaseClass))
   ...
   Blah Blah Blah code...
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

N.B. I cannot use View -> Tab Order; unfortunately.

Comment: Could you expand quickly on how you are setting the tab indexes in your solution? Have you defined the order else where and then assigned the values using GenerateTabIndex?

I'm dealing with a similar problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557390/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here since I just found it.

Use the WebControl class; it has the TabIndex Method build in. I was attempting to use the Control class.

Comment: That's correct. All controls in the System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace inherit from the WebControl class.